# Why can dask.dataframe.apply only process a column called 'name'?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dask

I am attempting to port some Pandas (Python) code to Dask instead. I am using Pandas 1.1.3 and Dask 2.30.0. I keep ramming my head against a wall I can't see. That is, I cannot understand what is going on here. I have boiled it down to the following minimal working example:
My data is the file 'test.csv' containing the following:

```
age,name
28,Alice
```

The following Python script (using Pandas) works fine:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", dtype={'name': str})
result = df['name'].apply(lambda text: text.upper())
#result = df['age'].apply(lambda num: num + 1)
print(result)
```

and prints:

```
0    ALICE
Name: name, dtype: object
```

The commented-out line operating on the 'age' column also works and prints:

```
0    29
Name: age, dtype: int64
```

Now, with Dask instead, my example becomes:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = dd.read_csv("test.csv", dtype={'name': str})
result = df['name'].apply(lambda text: text.upper(), meta={'name': str})
#result = df['age'].apply(lambda num: num + 1, meta={'age': int})
print(result.compute())
```

which works fine just like the Pandas example. However, if I try the commented-out line operating on the 'age' column instead, Python complains with the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_dask.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(result.compute())
  File "/some/path/miniconda3/envs/testdask/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 167, in compute
    (result,) = compute(self, traverse=False, **kwargs)
  File "/some/path/miniconda3/envs/testdask/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 452, in compute
    results = schedule(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
  File "/some/path/miniconda3/envs/testdask/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/threaded.py", line 76, in get
    results = get_async(
  File "/some/path/miniconda3/envs/testdask/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 486, in get_async
    raise_exception(exc, tb)
  File "/some/path/miniconda3/envs/testdask/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 316, in reraise
    raise exc
  File "/some/path/miniconda3/envs/testdask/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 222, in execute_task
    result = _execute_task(task, data)
  File "/some/path/miniconda3/envs/testdask/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/core.py", line 121, in _execute_task
    return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))
  File "/some/path/miniconda3/envs/testdask/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/optimization.py", line 961, in __call__
    return core.get(self.dsk, self.outkey, dict(zip(self.inkeys, args)))
  File "/some/path/miniconda3/envs/testdask/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/core.py", line 151, in get
    result = _execute_task(task, cache)
  File "/some/path/miniconda3/envs/testdask/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/core.py", line 121, in _execute_task
    return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))
  File "/some/path/miniconda3/envs/testdask/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/utils.py", line 29, in apply
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/some/path/miniconda3/envs/testdask/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py", line 5306, in apply_and_enforce
    c = meta.name
  File "/some/path/miniconda3/envs/testdask/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5139, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Even if I just call the 'name' column something else, it also fails like this. It is as if Dask is only able to work on columns of a DataFrame that are called 'name'. This seems extraordinarily weird to me, and I must be misunderstanding something. What is really going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The docs](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.Series.apply) seem to suggest that the `dict` should work, so that's weird, but if you replace the `meta` argument with a tuple instead, your code runs as expected:

```py
df = dd.read_csv("test.csv")
result = df['age'].apply(lambda num: num + 1, meta=('age', 'int64'))
print(result.compute())
```

becomes

```
0    29
Name: age, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Great, that seems to solve it. It still puzzles me, though...

Comment: According to [this answer on GitHub](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/7622#issuecomment-830983574) the behavior is expected, but the error message could be better.

Comment: Thanks for reporting it so we got this clarified.